# Saving exception message in database using django

Tags: django

i want to store my exception in database using django. 
 How i can do this. is there any  libaray to do this task to store exception in database.

Answer (score 0):

Define your exceptions as Django models.

Comment: Please explain it your answer.i am new to django

Comment: Well Django essentially defines database tables from special python classes, called Django models.

In Python you can raise pretty much anything, including Django model instances.

Comment: ok thanks. we can catch exception globally in asp.net using global file.anywhere exception occurs our application globall file catch the exception.how do this in django application.how we can catch exception in django globally>

Comment: In Python exceptions are only caught by try blocks. In Django some middleware exist that will catch all exceptions and email them to the admins. If you plan on storing them, you could make your own Django middleware for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have finished one project like you want.

We have a website with a non-Django Python engine. I have created a simple Django project that

1. Receives an information about a new exception via http request. There is a global try-catch in the basic project. If exception occurs then http request sends with details of exception. So, we need a special view which receives the information about new exceptions.
2. Shows the information about exception groups and exceptions. **Exception group** is a group of similar exceptions. Exceptions are in the same group if they have very similar *traceback*. I use the next function to check if the exceptions in the group:

   ```
   def are_slightly_diff( s1, s2 ):
       """ Returns True if s1 is similar to s2. 
           s1 and s2 are several strings in one (slashn-separated). """

       similar_count = 0

       s2_list = list( s2 )

       for ch in s1:
           try:            
               i_s2 = s2_list.index( ch )
           except ValueError:
               pass
           else:
           del s2_list[ i_s2 ]

       len_s2_list = len( s2_list )

       max_diff = int( len( s1 ) * 0.1 )

       if max_diff < 1:
           max_diff = 1

       return len_s2_list <= max_diff
   ```

So I have 2 models - the one for exception group:

```
class ExceptionItemGroup( models.Model ):

    _NEW_GROUP_NAME = 'Exceptions {0}'

    name = models.CharField( max_length = 512 )
    last_line = models.TextField() # matching template
    prev_lines = models.TextField()

    created_dt = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add = True )
    last_modified_dt = models.DateTimeField( auto_now = True )

    def rename( self, name ):
        self.name = name

    @staticmethod
    def find( cur_lines, site_id ):
        """ Find an exception group corresponding to the exception item. 
            Exc_item must contain formalized exception. """

        # 1) Check prev_lines
        cur_prev_lines = cur_lines[ : -1 ]

        cur_last_line = cur_lines[ -1 ]

        similar_groups = ExceptionItemGroup.objects.filter( site_id = site_id, prev_lines = list2line( cur_prev_lines ) )

        for sim_g in similar_groups:        
            if are_slightly_diff( cur_last_line, sim_g.last_line ):
                return sim_g # group was found        
        return None # group was not found

    @staticmethod
    def create_from_data( site_id, exc_lines, name ):
        " Use this method if a group was not found. "        

        with transaction.commit_on_success():
            g = ExceptionItemGroup( site_id = site_id, name = name )

            g.prev_lines = list2line( exc_lines[ : -1 ] )
            g.last_line = exc_lines[ -1 ]    
            g.save()

        return g

    def __unicode__( self ):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'exc_item_group'
```

And the other for exceptions which are in the groups (so, the model have a foreign key):

```
class ExceptionItem( models.Model ):
    group = models.ForeignKey( ExceptionItemGroup )
    title = models.TextField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created_dt = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add = True )

    @staticmethod
    def create( group, title, html ):

        item = ExceptionItem( group = group, title = title, body = html )
        item.save()

    def __unicode__( self ):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'exc_item'
```

There are views to navigate between exceptions:

1. The view with list of exception groups
2. The view with list of exceptions in a group
3. The view with full exception info receved from a basic project.